# tk installation doesn't work for ruby1.9.1

Tags: 12.04, ruby, tcl

Ok, this is what I did before I landed onto a terminal with a bunch of error messages...

---

First, I installed ruby1.9.1 using apt-get. 
(All of those ruby1.9.1 packages including ruby1.9.1-examples and  ruby1.9.1-full).

Then, I installed tcl8.5 and tk8.5 including their dev packages similarly.

Then, I installed libtcltk-ruby1.9.1

As expected, ruby --version says that I have got

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

But in irb, when I require 'tk' it says:

```
RuntimeError: tcltklib: fail to Tk_Init(). Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.5/tk8.5 /usr/lib/tk8.5 /usr/local/lib/tcltk/tk8.5 /usr/local/share/tcltk/tk8.5 /usr/lib/tcltk/tk8.5 /usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5 /lib/tk8.5 /usr/library

/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5/tk.tcl: version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.5.10, need     exactly 8.5.11
version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.5.10, need exactly 8.5.11
while executing
"package require -exact Tk  8.5.11"
(file "/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5/tk.tcl" line 18)
invoked from within
"source /usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5/tk.tcl"
("uplevel" body line 1)
invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $file]"


This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.

from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tk.rb:31:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tk.rb:31:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tk.rb:1245:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tk.rb:1245:in `block in <module:TkCore>'
```

Similar procedure worked when I used ruby1.8 and same version of tcl and tk, but this doesn't seem to work. I think it has something to do with these packages and their dependencies.

So, finally my question is: How to install tk and ruby, if I want to program Tk GUI in ruby1.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open this file in your test editer as root "**/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5/tk.tcl**"
go to line18
change this: **package require -exact Tk  8.5.11**
To to this: **package require -exact Tk  8.5.10**

Comment: Thumbs up for tk.tcl file!

Seems like 8.5.11 has still got some bugs to be solved... 

Anyway, thanks!!